# Session value becomes null after setting response.setheader()

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

To set the session secure and http only I have included the following code in the program

```
String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly");
```

the servlet code is

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
    response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly");

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    HttpSession l_session   = this.sess_regen(request);
    //l_session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5); No Enough Rows Found to Peform Calculation
    *estsession l_s         = (estsession)l_session.getAttribute("ge_session");*
    if(l_s == null) { out.println("Illegal Attempt"); return; }
    String res = l_s.captcha_id;
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(85, 35, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
```

but null pointer exception is occurring at the point on the code in italics. Any help on the same.

Comment: You mean `l_session` is `null`? What exactly does `this.sess_regen(request)`?

Comment: Actually it checks whether  the session is available ie getsession(true)

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't put code in comments.

Comment: Have you checked whether the returned `HttpSession` from `this.sess_regen(request)` is `null`?

Comment: Actually it checks whether  the session is available ie getsession(true) if not null it will return  l_session (l_session.setAttribute("ge_session", l_s);)

Comment: if i am not using that set header null pointer will not occur on  HttpSession l_session   = this.sess_regen(request); but if i use that code then it will return null

Comment: is there any other way to set session  httponly and secure